# How to step into dependency code using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

When debugging my user code, I want to step into the code of a dependency that is installed e.g. with `pip install -e path/to/package`.

I tried to find a place within the project where dependencies are listed and can be browsed to open the source file to debug (e.g. this is possible in PyCharm via the "External Libraries" section).

I would like to step into and through dependency code, but cannot find a way to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be possible with the built-in debugging configuration. As far as I know, the only time it's not possible is when the Python dependencies are C codes (ex. OpenCV, pygame) because they are stored as *.so* files instead of Python files.

Let's say I have this structure:

```
main
└── test.py
pkgs
└── mypkg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── moduleA.py
    └── setup.py
```

I created `mypkg` based on [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) sample from the Python docs. I then installed it on my env using the same command you mentioned:

```
pip install -e /path/to/mypkg
```

In test.py I have this:

```
import moduleA
moduleA.add_two_num(1, 2)
```

First, make sure to set the VSCode interpreter to use the same env where you installed `mypkg`. See [Select and activate an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) from the VSCode docs.

Next, [create a debugging configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations) for test.py:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "program": "/path/to/test.py",
    "pythonPath": "/path/to/.virtualenvs/test-py37/bin/python",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
}
```

It is important here again to set `pythonpath` to point to the same `python` where you installed `mypkg`. Here I am using a virtualenv named `test-py37`.

Now, set a breakpoint on the line with the external package:

[image: breakpoint]

Then start the debugger (press <kbd>F5</kbd> or select it from the Debug panel then press the Play button). When the debugger stops at the breakpoint:
[image: step-into]

Just press the **Step Into** button (or <kbd>F11</kbd>) and VS Code should take you to the code for the external dependency. You can also open the file directly on VS Code, then put breakpoints on them. Once it's open on your editor, the next time you debug, it stops on those breakpoints.

[image: breakpoint on dependency]

Comment: Upvoted. Am I right that there is no way to directly set the breakpoints in the module files - not needing to step through starting from the user code?

Comment: @phaebz You can open the module files directly on VS Code, and put breakpoints on them. Either you do **Open File** manually or **Go to Definition** to open the target file. I find that as long as you select the correct interpreter and debugger configuration, VS Code can step-into those module files.

Answer (score 7):

Disable `justMyCode` in the launch.json file. This is enabled by default.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "my_package",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

This helped me resolve issue on **Studio Version: 1.63.2 (Universal)**

Comment: thank you for pointing out the `"justMyCode": false`! That was the solution for me!