# How to open symbols of Python dependencies?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

In vscode, how can I open symbols in the dependencies of my Python project?

PyCharm indexes these symbols so I can access them via Navigate - Symbol (⌥⌘O).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pylance language server will index symbols in files opened during the session. So, if a 3rd party dependency file outside the workspace is opened, its symbols will be indexed and appear in **Go to Symbol in Workspace (⌘T)**

See also this issue: [Provide a way to search for symbols in libraries #35](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/35)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is part of the [Autocomplete and Intellisense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_autocomplete-and-intellisense) settings of VS Code.

#### For your own custom packages/modules

Let's say I have this sample structure:

```sh
.
├── main.py
└── mypkg
    ├── __init__.py
    └── mymod.py
```

where *main.py* contains:

```py
from mypkg import mymod
mymod.myfunc()
```

1st, you need to add the paths to your custom packages/modules in your workspace's *.vscode/settings.json*:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/path/to/mypkg"
]
```

Next, it's best to reload VS Code for changes in *settings.json* to take effect.

Then, you should now be able to right-click on the symbol (ex. `myfunc`) and either do **Go to Definition** or **Go to Declaration** or **Peek**.

[image: go to definition]

[image: peek]

#### For external or 3rd-party symbols

You just have to make sure that the currently selected Python interpreter is the same one where you installed the external or 3rd-party package. You can set the interpreter from the command palette as "*Python: Select Interpreter*". You can check the currently set interpreter on the lower-right section of the status bar (ex. shown on the image below as "test-py37").

[image: status bar]

Then make sure to set that same Python interpreter in your workspace's *.vscode/settings.json*:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/path/to/.venvs/test-py37/bin/python",
```

AFAIK, you only have to set the interpreter once ("*Python: Select Interpreter*"), which would automatically set `python.pythonPath` in *settings.json*. Then save your workspace. Every time you open the workspace again, it will use the same interpreter.

Then it will be the same way as for your custom packages/modules, you can use **Go to Definition** or **Go to Declaration** or **Peek**. For example, I installed `numpy` in my `test-py37` virtual environment. I can do **Peek > Peek Definition** to navigate to any of numpy's functions.

[image]

#### Note

Some Python packages are actually implemented in C, and so they are installed in your site-packages as *.so* files. For example, **OpenCV** for Python will be installed as **cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so** (on a Mac). For these kinds of packages, the **Go to Definition** or **Peek** features won't work as well:

[image: peek opencv]

Comment: Thanks. I'd also like to navigate from a stack trace to a 3rd-party symbol. Is this possible? eg: In PyCharm I can navigate to `full_dispatch_request` in flask using **Navigate - Symbol (⌥⌘O)**. The closest equivalent I can find in vscode is **Go to Symbol in Workspace (⌘T)** but this doesn't index 3rd-party symbols.

Comment: @tekumara I don't use PyCharm, so I don't really understand what you mean. If this is for running your code through a debugger, you can setup a [Python debugging configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging), then add breakpoints on specific lines, and then step into the dependencies. See my other answer on [How to step into dependency code using Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57165307/2745495). It works the same as **Go to Definition** but it's during a debugging session.

Comment: @tekumara Also, during debugging, VS Code will open a Variables and a Call Stack panels on the left side, to show you the symbols and their values as you step through the code. Maybe the [Debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) section of the VS Code docs can help answer your question.

Comment: thanks again.. I'm not actually using the debugger, but working off a stack trace I've been sent. I want to navigate to one of the functions in the stack trace, which is located in a third-party dependency. But I can only seem to navigate to symbols inside my code base (ie: workspace).

Answer (score 0):

The latest Pylance Language Server (2022.9.20) has a bug that it fails to find source files if no `[tool.pyright]` section in `pyproject.toml`

I've found this issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3366

After adding `[tool.pyright]` section in `pyproject.toml`, **⌘T** works well for me.